# Insert escape secuences with RegEx replace in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, escaping, google-sheets-formula

I want to split a string by a new line separator matching with Regex in Google Sheets

My formula is like this (this is a simplification):

```
=REGEXREPLACE("H98064595H98064579";"(\w\d{8})(\w\d{8})";"$1\n$2")
```

The result is:

```
H98064595nH98064579
```

I want a cell with this content:

```
H98064595
H98064579
```

The matching is ok, but the replace looks like don't works with escape sequences (new line, carriage return, horizontal tab,...)

Does Google Sheets' Regex supports replace escape sequences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this out:

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10); 1; REGEXEXTRACT("H98064595H98064579"; "(\w\d{8})(\w\d{8})"))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=REGEXREPLACE("H98064595H98064579","(\w\d{8})(\w\d{8})","$1"&CHAR(10)&"$2")
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=REGEXREPLACE("H98064595H98064579"; "(\w\d{8})(\w\d{8})"; "$1
 $2")
```

[image: 0]